# What is Address Sequencing?

Tags: computer-architecture

Whenever I've come across this question whether on the internet or in my class everybody mentions the 4 address sequencing capabilities required in a control memory and the steps of address sequencing:
1. Incrementing of the control address register
2. Unconditional branch 
... Etc.
But what is the "definition" of address sequencing?
How do I explain it in 1-2 lines ?

Answer (score 0):

Address sequencing is a process used to retrieve and analyze data from a computer's memory. It is an essential component of computer architecture and refers to the way in which computers locate and access data stored in memory.